# How to adjust my NetBeams IDE java application with windows maximizing

Tags: javascript, java, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I have developed my java application on NetBeans IDE. The problem is whenever I maximize the window size after running my application, size of application remains the same i.e; application size doesn't extends and fit to the screen. What could be the possible reasons or should I need to add some specific code or settings.

Comment: Use one or more appropriate layouts

Comment: Have you disabled the maximize button?